# how to get id from one table an add another table in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I am try to add id from one table to another table to give a relationship to the tables. 
i have 2 table ..

1. classes.(id,cls,divn)

id  cls   divn
1   1       A
2   1       B
4   2       A
5   2       B

6   2       C

7   3       A

2.teacher(id teachername,tclsid,tsub)

Now i want ,im enter teachername and select class,division ,subject on select box using html tag.
if im select class and division check to classes table.and get id from selected class & division to insert into teacher table tclsid feld.

how its possible??

im trying to select multiple class and division

im using controller.php is here

`$clss =implode(',', Input::get('tcls'));
          $divn =implode(',', Input::get('tdivn'));
          $teachers =new ForumTeacher();
          $teachers ->tname=Input::get('tname');
          $teachers->tmobile=Input::get('tmobile');
          $teachers ->ttype=Input::get('ttype');
          $teachers ->tsubject = implode(',', Input::get('tsubject'));
           $cs = ForumClass::where('cls', $clss)->where('divn', $divn )->first();
         $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;`

but not work this code         $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;` ...

i want teacher table like this

id     teachername   tclsid    tsub

1          xyz         1,5        maths

2          poq         5,7        english

if xyz teacher select class &division are 1,2 & A,B(so id is 1,5)

if poq teacher select class &division are 2,3 & B,A (so id is 5,7)

but i got an error 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Trying to get property of non-object
error code line is 
 $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;

Answer (score 0):

Your `$teachers` var is holding a new, unsaved ForumTeacher model. You have not assigned the `tcls` value in `$teachers`. So the `$teachers['tcls']` is not set, Add:

```
$teachers->tcls = $cs->id;
```

I don't understand what your are trying to do with:

```
$clsid[$cs->id] = $teachers['tcls'];
```

If you set the `tcls` attribute of `$teachers` first, what you are doing is the same as:

```
$clsid[$cs->id] = $cs->id;
```

Don't forget to save the model when you are done setting its attributes:

```
$teachers->save();
```

Comment: thank you sir ...i got answer myself........        im just try this code  $clsid[$cs->id] = $teachers['tcls']; ......  the correct code is this $cs = ForumClass::where('cls','=', $clss)->where('divn','=', $divn )->first();
            $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;

Comment: im trying to select multiple class and division using this code  <select name="tcls[]" id="tcls[]" multiple> my controller.php is             $clss =implode(',', Input::get('tcls'));
          $divn =implode(',', Input::get('tdivn'));  $cs = ForumClass::where('cls',$clss)->where('divn', $divn)->first(); $teachers->tcls= $cs->id; i got an error 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Trying to get property of non-object                                              inthis code $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;

Comment: I should have been more specific about adding $teachers->tcls = $cs->id, that you should add it after the line in your code that sets the $cs->id to ForumClass::where('cls', $clss)->where('divn', $divn )->first(). Your query for $cs->id is correct, the '=' is assumed if you provide only two arguments to the where() method.

Comment: sorry if dont mine........ can you write that 2 line code..                            are you saying like this                        $cs = ForumClass::where('cls','=',$clss)->where('divn','=',$divn)->first();
            $teachers->tcls= $cs->id;

Answer (score 0):

Get id from one table an add another table in Laravel 4.

```
$cs = ForumClass::where('cls','=', $clss)->where('divn','=', $divn )->first();
$teachers->tcls= $cs->id;
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Reread your question and code and from what I understand you are getting multiple class, division combinations and subject for multiple teachers. You either have to have one teacher and one cls and one divn and one subject or the same number of these corresponding to different teachers. Otherwise, I am confused by your model, so I am assuming you have one of each per teacher instance.

Then you need to iterate over the inputs and create one teacher at a time or create an array and batch create them. I'll do the iteration for simplicity of following it:

```
// assuming all input arrays have the same count() of elements and
// are all in the same order
$tclss = Input::get('tcls');
$tdivns = Input::get('tdivn');
$tnames = Input::get('tname');
$tmobiles = Input::get('tmobile');
$ttypes = Input::get('ttype');
$tsubjects = Input::get('tsubject');

$iMax = count($tclss);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iMax; $i++)
{
    $tcls = ForumClass::where('cls', $tclss[$i])->where('divn', $tdivns[$i])->get();
    if (is_null($tcls))
    {
        // cls, divn combination is missing from your table
        // if you want to add it then do so or handle the error
        $tcls = new ForumClass();
        $tcls->cls = $tclss[$i];
        $tcls->divn = $divns[$i];
        $tcls->Save();
    }

    $teacher = new ForumTeacher();
    $teacher->tname = $tnames[$i]; 
    $teacher->tmobile = $tmobiles[$i]; 
    $teacher->ttype = $ttypes[$i]; 
    $teacher->tsubject = $tsubjects[$i]; 
    $teacher->tcls = $tcls->id;

    $teacher->save();
}
```

I did not test this but you get the idea of what to do.

Comment: this code is work ..but i dont want this method....i only want concatenation of class id. (eg:if xyz teacher select class &division are 1,2 & A,B(so id is 1,5)

if poq teacher select class &division are 2,3 & B,A (so id is 5,7) .database (table:teacher) save tclsid field like this 1,5 and next row  tclsid field like this 5,7